# dotnet publish “Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json”

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, aws-toolkit

I am getting error :

> Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

with **dotnet publish**

I am trying to deploy docker base asp.net core solution from **visual studio 2017**
with **Amazon Tool Kit** to **AWS ECS**.

I found several links but those do not work for me.

I tried by restarting docker service and Visual Studio also.

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2880 people here seems to be experiencing the same issue as yours. Have you tried all the solutions?

Comment: @noobed Yes, i have tried all those. Have you faced the same issue?

Comment: not yet, I would need a MVP to test it on my own, to dig deeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me issue is with the corporate firewall.

After spending hours on the issue it gets resolved.

Before trying all other ways please try this first. This will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with multiple Net Core 2.1 SDKs. I bypassed the issue with using a different `runtime` parameter, specifically `win-x64` vs `win10-x64`. I'm not sure why this worked though

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me is,I have changed Target framework from .net core 3.1 to 2.1 and then again added dockerfile to the project.
[*I'm using Vs-2019]

[image: Project prop-> Target Framwork]

[image: Updated Docker file]